# Joining two columns with month and year separated into one to do the subtraction for days

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns separated in my dataframe, one have month and the other have the year when the store received a competitor. What I am trying to do is join those columns and then subtract from the date to get the values day by day. But running my code that I leave below, I get  an error that I am not able to unveil what that means. I will let the error bellow code.

```
# competition since
df2['competition_since'] = df2.apply(lambda x: datetime( year=x['competition_open_since_year'], month=x['competition_open_since_month'], day=1, axis=1 ))
df2['competition_time_month'] = ( ( df2['date'] - df2['competition_since'])/30 ).apply(lambda x: x.days).astype(int)
```

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/sales_predict_rossmann/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'competition_open_since_year'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-ac751656b323> in <module>
      1 # competition since
----> 2 df2['competition_since'] = df2.apply(lambda x: datetime( year=x['competition_open_since_year'], month=x['competition_open_since_month'], day=1, axis=1 ))
      3 df2['competition_time_month'] = ( ( df2['date'] - df2['competition_since'])/30 ).apply(lambda x: x.days).astype(int)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/sales_predict_rossmann/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7766             kwds=kwds,
   7767         )
-> 7768         return op.get_result()
   7769 
   7770     def applymap(self, func, na_action: Optional[str] = None) -> DataFrame:

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/sales_predict_rossmann/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    183             return self.apply_raw()
    184 
--> 185         return self.apply_standard()
    186 
    187     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/sales_predict_rossmann/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    274 
    275     def apply_standard(self):
--> 276         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    277 
    278         # wrap results

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/sales_predict_rossmann/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    288             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    289                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 290                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    291                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    292                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

<ipython-input-30-ac751656b323> in <lambda>(x)
      1 # competition since
----> 2 df2['competition_since'] = df2.apply(lambda x: datetime( year=x['competition_open_since_year'], month=x['competition_open_since_month'], day=1, axis=1 ))
      3 df2['competition_time_month'] = ( ( df2['date'] - df2['competition_since'])/30 ).apply(lambda x: x.days).astype(int)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/sales_predict_rossmann/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    851 
    852         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 853             return self._get_value(key)
    854 
    855         if is_hashable(key):

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/sales_predict_rossmann/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    959 
    960         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 961         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    962         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    963 

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/sales_predict_rossmann/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'competition_open_since_year'
```

Comment: KeyError means the column 'competition_open_since_year' does not exist. Typo maybe?

Comment: The column exists, I don't know why this error is returning. Any suggestion on how to find out?

Answer (score 0):

When you apply lambda functions to dataframes, the values of the columns get passed to it. So the input for your lambda function is values of the dataframe. I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
import datetime

df2['competition_since'] = df2['competition_open_since_month'] + "/1/" + df2['competition_open_since_month']

df2['competition_since'] = df2['competition_since'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

After this you could subtract from the date column to find the difference over each day. Like this (I don't think you need to divide by 30):

```
(df2['date'] - df2['competition_since']).apply(lambda x: x.days)
```